# Convert Postgresql Query to Hibernate Query using Criteria Builder

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have this sql Query :

```
select * from my_schema.user_account where CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM (CURRENT_DATE - mail_validated_date)) AS INTEGER)  % 15 = 0;
```

how to use criteria builder to make this condition ?